# adoconnection username and password

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado, adoconnection

i have an adoconnection in my form and use Access 2010 ( accdb database )

i set password in access for my DB

when i try to set this pass to Delphi i have some trouble :

1 : Delphi ask username and i have not any username .
2 : when i set password in ado ( with admin username or blank username ) i see this error :

test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider . cannot start your application . the workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user .

- the DB file is not open when i receive this error .

Comment: Database password is a different thing in access databases, it encrypts the db, it is not related with user access. Leave user name and password alone and indicate database password in the connection string with 'Database Password=[mypassword]' or in the last page of the connection builder.

Comment: thank you but it doesent worked . i recieve that error again . i set it from the last page of the connection builder .

Comment: Then my guess is that, you're also not providing correct 'user name'/'password'.

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password=mswin;Data Source=C:\DB1.accdb;Mode=Share Deny Read|Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="";Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;

Comment: Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False                             its my connectionstring and my password in access is  mswin

Comment: According to that connection string your 'Database Password' is empty, but in the question you've told you have one. Also the connection string has a 'Password' for the default user (mswin). I guess it's all mixed up, I suggest you to clear the `ConnectionString` property of the ADOConnection in the OI and then start over.

Comment: yeah :) thank you so much .... it dosent has thanks button or vote button to thank you more :)

Comment: Oh, don't worry about it, you can accept the answer I posted :) And you're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database password for access databases is not related with user level access rights, it is used for encrypting the database.

You can indicate the database password in the connection string with `Database Password=mypass` for Jet/ACE OLE DB or `Pwd=mypass` for OLE DB for ODBC or set it in the last page of the connection builder.

Comment: I don't believe you can specify the database password with ODBC, but I only use Access directly, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Also, database passwords are a complete waste of time, nothing but security theater, and if you can get rid of it, you'll be better off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
After some research, I had success with the following connection-string:

```
'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
+';Jet OLEDB:Database Password='+Password
+';Data Source='+FileName
+';Persist Security Info=False';
```